# How to upload the local image to Firebase Storage in TinyMCE (ReactJs integration)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tinymce

I want to upload the image to firebase storage as soon as the user uploads a local image in the editor.

```js
function uploadToFirebaseStorage(file){
    return fileURL
}
```

I have created a function to upload to firebase but how do I pass the 'image file' to my function?
I have looked into [images_upload handler](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/general-configuration-guide/upload-images/#images_upload_handler) but how do I access the user uploaded file inside that function?

Comment: Open the example in codepen and check Line 31 of [this example](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/file-image-upload/#liveexample)

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi well thank you, but how do I write line 41 in my reactjs init prop? I can't access 'tinymce' there.

Comment: what do you mean by `reactjs init prop` ? can you make a simple sandbox of what you have done sofar? You need to monitor the `onchange` handler of the Editor component

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi this is the sandox link https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-easley-xljuv?file=/src/App.js.  Reference  taken from here -https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/integrations/react/#tinymcereactintegrationquickstartguide.

How do I write the line 41 of the codepen you mentioned? Because i can't access tinymce in the int props.

Comment: Well you are right, the React integration is tricky. I think the only way is to some how to manipulate the `<pluginName>.min.js` that this library uses. Or write another prop , `onAfterImageUpload` that returns that `cdn4 url` of the image. Sorry :(

Comment: Or use the existing `onSetContent` get the `e.target` create HTML of the content string (which is that added HTML tag in a string format) and check if the tag is `img` the upload the `src` to firebase. Or first, download the blob from URL then upload the file to firebase

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi actually, I can't understand the second method you mentioned.